# How would I trim the input to a JQuery auto-complete box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

Is there any way to trim (remove leading/trailing spaces) the input entered by a user into a jQuery auto-completing text `<input>` box before it is matched against the list of names:values? I currently have a textbox in which users are meant to enter names. The names are then matched against a list of name:value pairs by jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var resources = [
               <?php 
                    foreach($data['Resource'] as &$row){
                        $Name = $row['Forename']." ".$row['Surname'];  
                        echo "{";
                        echo "  label:'$Name',";
                        echo "  value:'$row[EmployeeNumber]'";
                        echo "},";
                    }
                 ?>
                ];

    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#Resource').autocomplete({
            source: resources,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery('#Resource').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },          
            select: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery('#Resource').val(ui.item.label);
                jQuery('#EmployeeNumber').val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

My problem is that if the user enters a name that matches one in the `resources` map, but with spaces after it, it won't be matched and thus no value will be assigned to the input. I would like for trailing spaces at least (if not also leading spaces) to be ignored on this mapping if possible.

Additionally, would it be possible to add a default value for the input box if no map is found?

**EDIT:**

As an aside, is it possible to have a no-match entry shown in the drop-down autocomplete box if the user types something that doesn't match? Apologies for the after-question edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the find yourself in the `source` function, instead of using [the built-in function](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L322), like this:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
  var matcher = new RegExp($.trim(request.term).replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), "i" );
  response($.grep(resources, function(value) {
    return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
  }));
}
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5wLAq/).  This uses [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to trim down the search term before it gets passed into [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to get the leading/trailing white-space ignorant effect you want.

---

For your edit, you can do this, but the "No Result..." will be selectable, [give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5wLAq/2/):

```
source: function( request, response ) {
  var matcher = new RegExp($.trim(request.term).replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), "i" );
  var matches = $.grep(resources, function(value) {
    return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
  });
  response(matches.length ? matches : [{ label: 'No Result Found', value: '' }]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Nick, this works like a charm! Only problem I had was that I needed to replace the "$"s with jQuery - I didn't spot at first that the "jQuery" was missing and spent far too long trying to think of complicated reasons that might cause it to not work on my end!

Comment: Sorry if this seems a bit rude, but just wanted to check - is there definetely no way to make the 'No Result Found' choice unselectable, or do you just not know of any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jQuery.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
jQuery.trim(yourValue);
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough in my question (will edit it in a minute) - where exactly would I trim the data to make sure it is trimmed before jQuery tries to match it against the mapping list? My apologies, but the above was just taken mostly from an example on the web - never used jQuery before!

Comment: @Stephen, Which auto-complete plugin are you using?

Comment: As far as I am aware, we are using [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete). Thanks.